# Giving hokuyo persistent device names

Tags: usb, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I have multiple (3 to be precise) hokuyo cameras all going through usb. My problem is that I want each of them to have a specific name (i.e. the back camera is AMC0 and the side camera is AMC1 etc.). I have looked into writing a udev rule for that but I haven't been lucky in that department. I have the specific ID for each camera but I do not know how to link that to a name.

Any help is appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172765/giving-hokuyo-persistent-device-names/) by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use this udev rule:

```
# Hokuyos
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Hokuyo Data Flex for USB", ATTRS{product}=="URG-Series USB Driver", MODE="0666", GROUP="dialout", PROGRAM=="/etc/ros/run.sh hokuyo_node getID %N q", SYMLINK+="sensors/hokuyo_%c"
```

It's gonna need /etc/ros/run.sh, which basically is:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/ros/setup.sh 
rosrun $@
```

Where /etc/ros/setup.sh is a symlink to your ROS setup.sh file in /opt/ros/???/setup.sh.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-06-04**:
Does this apply to each hokuyo? Or are there edits I need to make to that rule to make it specific to each camera? @dornhege

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-04**:
Works for every one that I've worked with, i.e. URG-04LX, Simple-URG, UTM 30-LX

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-06-04**:
maybe i'm just a total dingbat, but how do I decide what that particular device is going to be consistently called? @dornhege

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-04**:
The names are /dev/sensors/hokuyo_serial

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-06-04**:
so how does it give a unique and persistent name to each camera? @dornhege

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-04**:
The serial numbers are unique.

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-06-04**:
I followed your steps exactly and I don't see anything named hokuyo_serial or serial numbers in /dev/sensors/ @dornhege

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-04**:
You'll have to restart udev, unplug and replug your sensors before udev creates the new symlinks for them. You may also want to review the udev log to make sure that it isn't encountering any errors.

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-06-04**:
so then in my hokuyo launch files, what do i tell it to launch? @ahendrix

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-04**:
You should run the hokuyo_node normally, passing it the new symlink in /dev/sensors/ as the port parameter.

**Comment by [GWall](https://answers.ros.org/users/12481/gwall/) on 2014-06-09**:
Hey, just saying that I got it to work! Thanks for all your responses and putting up with my ignorance! Greatly appreciated! @dornhege @ahendrix

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following udev rule uses the latest installed ROS version. Make sure to restart or run `sudo udevadm trigger` to load and trigger the rule.

```
#### Install ###############################################################################
# sudo cp 90-HokuyoLidarRules.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/                                     #
# sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo service udev restart && sudo udevadm trigger #
############################################################################################

# Hokuyo USB Lidars
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="15d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="dialout", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '$(find /opt/ros -name env.sh | sort -r | head -1) rosrun urg_node getID %N q'", SYMLINK+="sensors/hokuyo_%c"
```

Source: https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/mobility_base_ros/src/42ba6e1b56d43897a3666d015ff09e2859f608b5/mobility_base_bringup/udev/90-HokuyoLidarRules.rules?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

The [mobility_base_bringup](https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/mobility_base_ros/src/default/mobility_base_bringup/) package also installs the udev rules when installed as a binary Debian package.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kivrakh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31606/kivrakh/) on 2017-08-17**:
perfect!, I tried a couple of things. But, this is working very well. Thank you!

**Comment by [MMH130](https://answers.ros.org/users/33933/mmh130/) on 2018-03-01**:
I get an error as follows :

```
ATTRS{idVendor}==15d1,: command not found
```

Do anyone knows anything about this error ?